# How do I separately get label and field?

Tags: 8

For form fields, we have label and field (Text/Select/...).

How do I get the field title and its value separately in a template file?

```
{{ form.title }}
```

I need both separately, so I can properly style.

Comment: label `form.title['#title']` value `form.title.0` **Note:** this will only get the first value, if it's a multi-value field you need to loop.

Comment: Thanks @NoSssweat In this way will get title. But how to get field separately as well

Comment: did you try `form.title.0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access separately labels and values for fields in twig template (example in node twig template: node.html.twig) I propose to loop all the node variable.

My example: 
Instead of print all content with this line {{ content }} loop the content object

```
    {% for item in node %}
        {# Print the label of the field #}
        {{ item.fieldDefinition.label }}

        {# Print the value of a field text/simple field #}
        {{ item.fieldDefinition.value }}

        {# Print the value of a field reference  #}
        {{ item.value[0]['target_id'] }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Other way is to use this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value